# An old anime where the protagonist stabs his eye to counter hypnosis and later on receives a bionic eye that can control vehicles

Tags: midnight-eye-gokuu

I can't remember the name of an anime I watched a long time ago (approximately 20 years). In this anime the main antagonist is a woman who can hypnotize people by getting naked and then drawing out some eye projectors and when people look at these projectors they go insane. I remember two main scenes from this anime, I hope this can help.

- In the first scene, two people look at a security camera, then the woman stands in front of the camera and manifests her eye projectors. Then one of the two men goes insane and jumps off the building and dies.
- In the second scene, the main protagonist drives in his car and then the woman jumps on top of a truck which is just in front of the protagonist's car. During the time the woman manifests her eye projectors, the main protagonist stabs one of his eyes so that he won't get hypnotized. I remember that after that the main protagonist's eye is replaced with a powerful bionic eye which gives him some super unnatural powers where he can control distanced vehicles by using mind control.

Thanks in advance for anyone who is willing to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the anime is  **[Midnight Eye: Gokuu](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1879/Midnight_Eye__Gokuu)**.

The actual scene differs a bit from your description: the two people were actually police investigating the baddie whose minions include the woman of a different biology with "peacock feathers" extending from her body who can mind control people. One of the police was observing a room through a telescope when the woman walked into his vision and hypnotized him into pushing his comrade off the balcony and following suit. Here's a screenshot of the woman:

[image: Woman displaying her peacock feathers to perform hypnosis]

The rest is as you have described, but the bionic eye not only can control distanced vehicles, it can control every electronic device in the world.

Comment: @JohnXargon You're welcome :) mind giving an upvote and accepting this answer?

Comment: I just did it...